# Issue with sealed interface type safety inside when - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sealed

In order to handle `Retrofit` api calls I have a sealed interface as below:

```
sealed interface DataSourceResponseWrapper<out T> {
    data class Success<out T>(val result: T) : DataSourceResponseWrapper<T>
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : DataSourceResponseWrapper<Nothing>
}
```

As you can see `Success<out T>` is a generic class but `Error` is not.

Here is `ItemDataRepository`:

```
class DataRepository constructor(private val itemApiDataSource: ItemApiDataSource) {

    suspend fun loadData(search: String, days: Int, aqi: Boolean, alerts: Boolean): DataSourceResponseWrapper<LocalItemResponse> =
        coroutineScope {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val response = try {
                    DataSourceResponseWrapper.Success(weatherApiDataSource.getWeatherInfo(search, days, if (aqi) "yes" else "no", if (alerts) "yes" else "no"))
                } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
                    DataSourceResponseWrapper.Error(throwable)
                }

                when (response) {
                    is DataSourceResponseWrapper.Success<ApiWeatherResponse> ->
                        DataSourceResponseWrapper.Success(WeatherConverter.convertToLocal(response.result))
                    is DataSourceResponseWrapper.Error -> response
                }
            }
        }
```

In `DataRepository` class I check if the result is successful or not. If it is, repository class converts the returned `ApiItemResponse` to a `LocalItemResponse` and returns the result. And if it's not, returns the `response` itself

The code works perfectly fine **until** I change `when` statements to the following:

```
                when (response) {
                    is DataSourceResponseWrapper.Success<ApiWeatherResponse> ->
                        DataSourceResponseWrapper.Success(WeatherConverter.convertToLocal(response.result))
                    else -> response
                }
```

It gives me an error saying:

```
Required:
DataSourceResponseWrapper<LocalItemResponse>
Found:
DataSourceResponseWrapper<Any>
```

So my question is **Why Kotlin does not smartly cast the response as before?** And the other question is **How can I use `else` without needing to check type?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some cases are simply too sophisticated (too many steps of logic) for the compiler to sort out and infer the types for you. In this case, instead of using an `else` branch, you can be specific. This is the way you should be using a `sealed` type anyway (no `else` branch if it can be avoided):

```
when (response) {
    is DataSourceResponseWrapper.Success<ApiWeatherResponse> ->
                    DataSourceResponseWrapper.Success(WeatherConverter.convertToLocal(response.result))
    is DataSourceResponseWrapper.Error -> response
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I know it is the reason of using sealed classes to be specific when using with `when`. But consider the situation I add 10 Error classes (which does not take specific types) in my sealed class. At this point I have to write 10 more `is ... ->` statements which return `response` itself. Its not logical to me.

Comment: You could use `is DataSourceResponseWrapper<Nothing>` to cover all those Error cases. But a better design would be a single Error class with some property to distinguish the kind of error. Composition over inheritance.

Comment: Well thats a response i was looking for. I saw some code practices which they put multy Error classes to handle errors which I thought is not a good practice. Thank you mate

Answer (score 1):

You can in fact write

```
else -> response as DataSourceResponseWrapper<LocalItemResponse>
```

to make it work. Although the IDE is likely to warn for an unchecked cast. But it's just a warning. You can safely ignore it because you know for a fact that you can cast it there. It will compile and run just fine. But admittedly it is ugly to have the warning there.

Comment: Yes as you said I can ignore the warning but in my opinion its not the best practice to acheive the result in that way.